# How to Retrieve a YouTube Channel's Genre With YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to gather information about specific YouTube channels, like their # of subs, their language, country, and genre, and the only one of those I'm having trouble with finding is their genre. I think it may have something to do with the GuideCategories but I'm not 100% sure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In YouTube API v2, it has a [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#Custom_parameters) like `movie-genre` or `genre` to only include movies in a particular genre. Unfortunately, it is deprecated and I don't see those parameters in V3.

I think you're right in using [GuideCategories](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories) since it identifies a category that YouTube algorithmically assigns based on a channel's content.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#guideCategory",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": string
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!